# Jumio's NetverifySDK is not preselecting the provided country

Tags: android

I am using Jumio's NetverifySDK and trying to preselect a country when building the SDK object as specified in their [documentation](https://github.com/Jumio/mobile-sdk-android/blob/master/docs/integration_netverify-fastfill.md):

```
// ...
mNetverifySDK = NetverifySDK.create(getActivity(),
                    jumio.token, jumio.secret, JumioDataCenter.US);
            mNetverifySDK.setPreselectedCountry("MEX")
// ...
mJumioDocumentTypes.add(NVDocumentType.IDENTITY_CARD);
mJumioDocumentTypes.add(NVDocumentType.PASSPORT);
mNetverifySDK.setPreselectedDocumentTypes(mJumioDocumentTypes);
// ...
```

I'm then launching the Jumio activity:

```
startActivityForResult(mNetverifySDK.getIntent(), NetverifySDK.REQUEST_CODE);
```

After this, the first screen is Jumio's Country selection screen, so I'm taking that the SDK is not reading my country selection or that the specified country is not available.

Is there a bug on Jumio's Netverify SDK, or is the country I'm trying out ("MEX" = México) not available on Jumio?

What is weird is that even though I tried with a country different than "MEX", it scanned and verified a Mexican identity card without an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your api keys are configured incorrectly.